# php auto complete textbox wont work with more than 30 results

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

what im looking to find out is what about my code is why it wont auto complete when i have more than 30 results listing from a mysql query.

i have success with 5, 10, 20, and 29 results, but for some reason when i get above 30 it stops working. i have worked with limit 0 , 30 so adjust and find that i can only have 29 results working in my mysql query. and when viewing the source code the mysql query shows all the results but does not come up in the auto complete section.

you will see that this is tweeked to fill my needs from days of searching and finding this code it self. so please let me know if i have bastardized something

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    <?php include 'include/dbcon.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `kb_faq` WHERE `active` = 'yes' LIMIT 0 , 30";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo '"' . $row['question'] . '", ' . "\n";

  }
  ?>
      ""
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you limiting it with  `LIMIT 0 , 30`?

Comment: i am at current using limit to get it to work but i have over 70 results with out a limit. the data will over time grow and if all goes will it will be over 100 results in the near future. in a way i would like it to work like google. but i dont think i will every have that many results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [<?php 
    include 'include/dbcon.php';
    $sql = "SELECT question FROM `kb_faq` WHERE `active` = 'yes' LIMIT 0 , 50";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $tags = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
     $tags[] = "'".htmlentities($row['question'])."'";
    }
    echo implode(',', $tags);
    ?>];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```